# How do I correct error in opening cron editor?

Tags: unix

I am trying to open cron editor using command **crontab -e**
but I am getting error **fclose: There is not enough space in the file system.**

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk is full. Check `df -hk` to know which filesystem is at 100%. Afterwards, check what you can do to delete or copy obsolete files in order to clean your disk (the command `du -k . | sort -n` might be useful to find the highest diskspace usage directories).